# Customizing the People Lightning component's presentation in Lightning for Outlook

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce-for-outlook, lightning-outlook, email-application-pane

I'm really pleased to see the email application pane integration available now for Gmail and Outlook in the Lightning for Gmail and Lightning for Outlook feature sets. If you want to view Account and Contact data in the email pane, you appear to mostly want to heavily lean on the People Lightning Standard component.

I can't seem to find a way to customize the Contact and Account presentation in those panes of the People component, as I would expect to do with Page layouts in the Salesforce web app that users use. I can customize the actions under the + sign using Global Actions, but changing whether to show the Chatter feed or which Account or Contact record fields are display (or what order) appears to be impossible.

I'd like to present a more nuanced and user-focused view of Contacts and Accounts, preferably based on which Profile the user belongs to. Is there a clicks-not-code method for customizing the People component's data presentation?

Or am I stuck rolling my own starting with this example? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_custom_for_app_builder_email_app_pane.htm